# PayPal adaptive payments error: incorrect credentials

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-nvp, paypal-mpl

I'm implementing PayPal payments in iOS application. I need to transfer money from customer to merchant account so I'm using old MPL SDK with adaptive payments. All works. Now I need to verify payment on server side. For this I'm using `PaymentDetails` API method ([API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/)). But it always returns an error:

```
Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.
```

I've created an application on http://www.paypal-apps.com and requested API credentials in my PayPal profile. I've tried it with premier and business accounts. But still no results.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch from Live to Sandbox and the other way around you should care for the `config` of the mode.

Sadly I did this all in PHP, not with MPL SDK but this piece of code might be the right hint to you:

LIVE:

```
$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
  new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential('XXXXXXXXX...XXXXXXXXXX','YYYYYYY...YYYYYYYYY')
);  
$apiContext->setConfig( array('mode' => 'live') );
```

SANDBOX:

```
$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
  new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential('xxxxxxxxx...xxxxxxxxxx','yyyyyyyyyy...yyyyy')
);  
$apiContext->setConfig(array('mode' => 'sandbox'));
```

Do not forget to set your Mode according to your credentials (Secret Key). Paypal does not recognize the type of secret-key by its own.

Comment: My questions is not about new REST API but classic NVP/SOAP solution which not using OAuth.